# Set user timezone while display date and time using Laravel Carbon

Tags: php, date, datetime, laravel-5.5, php-carbon

I want to display date and time according to user's timezone. I'm getting user's timezone each time he login. Following is my code in view where I need to display comments date and time to users.

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $memoriesRow->createdAt, 'UTC')->setTimezone($timezone)->format('l, F dS Y h:i A') }}
```

But the date and time it showed is not correct, it's showing in future. Following is the date and timezone I'm passing to it:

```
Asia/Karachi - 2017-12-13 16:55:07
```

but it showed me this (09:55 PM is future time):

```
Wednesday, December 13th 2017 09:55 PM
```

Comment: add like $date->setTimezone('Asia/Karachi'); after $date = "Carbon\Carbon --- "

Comment: @AmitGupta ok checking..

Comment: @AmitGupta got exception: Call to a member function setTimezone() on string

Comment: Check my Answer. try like that.

Comment: What is coming in $memoriesRow->createdAt?

Comment: it must be like 2017-12-12 16:34:00

Comment: it's coming from database 2017-12-13 16:55:07

Comment: what I need is, when i add a comment I'll see created date/time according to my time, but when you see my comment you will see it's created date according to your timezone..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161108/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-umair-malik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```
$timestamp = $memoriesRow->createdAt;
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Asia/Karachi');
```

Comment: it still has difference, also how can i format using your mentioned method:

original date: 2017-12-13 16:55:07 - converted date: 2017-12-13 21:55:07

Comment: add Asia/Karachi in place of UTC once

Comment: What issue, tell me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161114/discussion-between-umair-malik-and-amit-gupta).

Comment: it was working fine with asia/karachi, but i tried to test it with 'America/Detroit' timezone but i remained as it is, date time didn't changed for this timezone

Comment: You need to get user timezone in one variable like $user_timezone.
In user timezone, Asia/Karachi or America/Detroit will come or any other user timezone.

Comment: Then you need to add below code:
$date = $date->setTimezone($user_timezone);
to change date time according to timezone.

Comment: You can try and let me know if you face any difficulty.